# Navigate to auxiliary route inside component

Tags: angular, routes

Given the following router link with custom outlet:

```
<a [routerLink="[{outlets: {"playListOutletName", ["playlist-path"]}]"]
```

How to navigate to this outlet and url inside the component:

```
  <button (click)=goToRoute()>


class MyComponent {

   constructor(private router: Router){}
   goToRoute(){
    #TODO this.router.navigate[] ??
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried like this? - `this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { "playListOutletName": ["playlist-path"] } }]);`

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
this.router.navigate([{ outlets: {'playListOutletName': ['playlist-path']} }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your template code is invalid:

- You don't need square brackets around the whole attribute, only the attribute name
- `outlets` is an object, so the property name `playListOutletName` should be followed by a colon rather than a comma.
- You need to use single quotes when you are already inside the double-quotes of the HTML attribute.

So all these changes in the template would look like this:

```html
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { 'playListOutletName': ['playlist-path'] } }]">Link text</a>
```

Secondly, to move this to the controller you can just pass this (corrected) value to `Router.navigate()`, like so:

```
class MyComponent {

  constructor(private router: Router){}

  goToRoute(){
    
    this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { 'playListOutletName': ['playlist-path'] } }]);

  }
}
```

Comment: The question was how to navigate in the controller. I believe the author's already made the navigation work successfully inside the template.

Comment: Not with the code they posted here they haven't! That is a definite error. Although point taken they did ask for navigation in the controller ;)